# Why is the compiler throwing me the error function overload?

Tags: c++

I am working in c++ and I am trying to find the 1001th prime number. When I run this code it throws error on line 14 that the function is overloaded. Can you tell me why it is throwing me the error? Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;



int main() {
    cout << "Hi in this program I will tell you the 1001th prime number" << endl;
    int number;
    for (int i = 2; i < 1000000; i++) {
        for (int prime = 2; prime < 1000000; prime ++) {
            if (prime % i != 0) {
                for (int count = 1; count < 100000; count ++) {}
                cout << count << prime << " is a prime number" << endl;// this line has the problem
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Copy-paste the error message instead of paraphrasing it.

Comment: Copy-paste the *complete* error message into the body of the question, including any informational notes.

Comment: What is this loop actually purposed for: `for (int count = 1; count < 100000; count ++) {}`?

Comment: the error message was           reference to overloaded function could not be resolved; did you mean to call it?

Comment: The loop is so I can count how much prime numbers there are in my loop

Comment: Remember to use `@` and then the username of the person you are replying to, or they won't be notified. The post owner is always notified, so I don't need it to address you here. I think the answer by hacoo is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "count" *variable* has it's scope only within the "for" loop.  That loop terminates with the '}' character at the end of line.

The count you are referencing on your cout line is from somewhere else.  I assume that somewhere in global scope you're pulling in definitions of two "count" functions and the compiler thinks you want to refernce one of those, but doesn't know which one to take.

Comment: Specifically, it's `std::count`, from `<algorithm>`, brought into scope by `using namespace std;`. No using directive would mean a better error message.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your curly braces after the for loop:

```
 for (int count = 1; count < 100000; count ++) {}
```

You're closing the for loop block before you get to the next line, where you reference 'count'. So, the count variable is not in scope when you try to print it. Try changing it to this:

```
            if (prime % i != 0) {
                for (int count = 1; count < 100000; count ++) {
                cout << count << prime << " is a prime number" << endl;
                } // closing curly brace is here now :)
            }
```